# What is wrong with my headset

Tags: mountain-bike, headset

I received a new carbon fork. Seller told me is was for a 56/40 bottom headset but after mounting it, here is the result.
I chose a ZS56/40 head set. What is wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pictured fork has an integrated crown race along with another crown race stuck on top that it doesn't need. Take that away and it hopefully should all be good.

The lower cup in the picture overhangs the headtube by an unusual amount, but I presume that's just by random chance because if that's an SHIS ZS56 lower cup then there's not really anything else it could have been crammed into.